# Rebol/Red parse: how to copy between 2 marks

Tags: parsing, rebol, red

I want to be able to parse between 2 marks in parse rule. For a contrieved example:

```
src: {a b c d e f}

rule: [
    to "b" mark1: thru "e" mark2: 
    to mark1 copy text to mark2
]
```

This doesn't work, text contains "[" instead of what I'd like to get:

```
b c d e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to implement a "DO desire" of copying using PARSE.  PARSE's COPY is looking for patterns, not treating the series as positions.

You can escape into DO in mid-parse via a PAREN!, it will run if the parse rule reaches that point.

```
src: {a b c d e f}

rule: [
    to "b" mark1: thru "e" mark2: 
    (text: copy/part mark1 mark2)
    to end ;-- not strictly necessary, but makes PARSE return true
]

parse src rule
```

That will give you text as `b c d e`

Note that you can't have it both ways, either with COPY or with TO.  `TO <series!>` meant "look for b", not "jump to the position of b".  So when you say `to mark1` you're invoking another match.  If you want to set the parse position to *the specific position* recorded in mark1, use `:mark1` in the parse rule.

Comment: as I said it's a contrieved example. so I updated the example where I have markers: at first div and closing div with nested div inside.

Comment: @user310291 If you would like to ask a new question, it's usually better to just do that...and be sure to be as clear as possible when you do.

Comment: ok see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088909/rebo-red-parse-is-it-possible-to-copy-between-two-marks-embedding-nested-div

Answer (score 1):

two alternative solutions/rules working in Red

```
rule: [
   to "b" copy text thru "e" to end
]
```

and

```
 rule: [ to "b" collect  [keep thru "e"] to end]
 text: first parse src rule
```