# Rebo/Red parse: Is it possible to copy between two marks embedding nested div

Tags: parsing, rebol, red

Subsequent to [Rebol/Red parse: how to copy between 2 marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087327/rebol-red-parse-how-to-copy-between-2-marks) let's now suppose I achieve to mark a string with some marks with a complex parse rule having nested div (whatever that rule), is there a general way to copy between mark1 and mark2, at least is there a specific way  for this kind of nested div example:

```
    {
        <div>
        a ; <- mark1
            <div>
                b
            </div>
            <div>
            c
            </div>
        d ; <- mark2
        </div> 

        <div>
        e
            <div>
                f
            </div>
            <div>
            g
            </div>
        h
        </div>  
    }


    rule: [
        mark1:
        ...
        mark2:
        copy mark1 to mark2
    ]
```

Comment: Are you able to get the `mark1` and `mark2` positions to hold the locations you've specified?  If so, it's not clear how this would be any different from the previous question.  PARSE's COPY keyword does not work how you are trying to use it.  It means `copy <target-variable> <rule>`, not `copy <starting-position> to <ending-position>`.  There is no PARSE keyword that does what you are asking, for two arbitrarily found locations.  PARSE's copy always starts copying from the current parse position, where you are, and always ends after a rule match, if the rule matches.

Comment: @HostileFork ok thanks that's what I fear. This makes parsing very difficult in some simple use case scenarios, that's a pity.

Comment: What is particularly difficult about `(text: copy/part mark1 mark2)`?  If you would like to return it from the parse as the overall result, RETURN is a parse keyword in Rebol3, so you can also say `return (copy/part mark1 mark2)`.

Comment: @Hostilefork like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097970/red-parse-with-break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no problem with the already shown solutions, but if you want to make it a little bit more complicated you could go back to an already defined / marked point in your src as in this example.

```
src: {1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz}
>> parse src [ skip mark: to "a" mark2:  :mark   to "3" mark1: to end]  
== true
>> mark1
== "34567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"
```

pay attention to *`:mark`* It set back the pointer to an prior defined point.

So the answer to your former question would look like that

```
rule: [
    to "b" mark1: thru "e" mark2: 
    :mark1 copy text to mark2
]
```

Here replace "b" and "e" according your your wished points, maybe "a" and "d".

Comment: sorry my example not good what I wanted to get is nth div block not a value especially.

Comment: Then prefix the wanted number of occurences in front of a sub rule or count the occurences as you did in one of your former questions

Comment: what I tried to get is rather this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097970/red-parse-with-break