# Red parse with break

Tags: rebol, red

my parse code with break doesn't work, I shouldn't get last div block in text:

```
src: {
<div class="main">
    <div>
        test
    </div>

    <div>
        test2
    </div>
    <div>
        test3
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
</div>
}

rules: [
    (div-count: 0)
    some [
        to "<div"
        (div-count: div-count + 1) [if (div-count = 1) mark1:] 
        |
        thru "</div>"
        (div-count: div-count - 1) [if (div-count = 0) mark2: break]
    ]

    text: copy/part mark1 mark2

]

parse src rules
print text
```

Expected result I want is:

```
    {
    <div class="main">
        <div>
            test
        </div>

        <div>
            test2
        </div>
        <div>
            test3
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer for Red and Rebol could look like this

```
rules: [
    (div-count: 0   clear rules/3/8 )
    some [
        mark:  "<div"  
        (if  equal? 1  div-count: div-count + 1  [
            mark1:  mark  
        ] )   | 
         "</div>"  mark2:
        ( 
        if equal? 0  div-count: div-count - 1  [
            text: copy/part mark1 mark2    
            insert rules/3/8 [to end]  
        ]  )  
        [] | skip
    ]
]
```

One of the problems with your rules are that you use *`to`*  and `|` (meaning or)  *`thru`*, so that most closing `</div>` s  would be skipped. The first match `<div` is satisfied and on to the next opening`<div` without comparing the following sub rules. But the cursor is not advancing, the next `<div` is still the same. Probably Red discovers the endless loop (no advancing) and interrupts it.

I use dynamically modified rules instead of `break`, as `break` breaks out of (sub) rules in Rebol, but does not stop the whole parsing process as you can see here.

```
 >> parse "aaa" [(n: 0)some ["a" [break] (ask form n: n + 1) ]]
 1
 2
 3
 == true
```

That's different to Red, where it interupts parse.

```
>> parse "aaa" [(n: 0)some ["a" [break] (ask form n: n + 1) ]]
1
== false
```

So a simple solution suitable for Red, not for Rebol can look like that

```
rules: [
    (div-count: 0)
    some [
        mark: "<div"
        (if  equal? 1  div-count: div-count + 1  [mark1:  mark]) 
        |
        "</div>" mark2:
        if (equal? 0  div-count: div-count - 1 )  
          [(print text: copy/part mark1 mark2 )  break]
        |
        skip
    ]
]
```

Comment: Could you explain why you do need clear rules/3/8 : do you change rules dynamically ?

Comment: I don't understand [] | skip either

Comment: still why conditional break doesn't work: is my program buggy or red buggy ?

Comment: tested program it works though I don't understand ;)

Comment: Yes, I change the rules dynamically. [] does nothing. It is just a place holder, that gets filled. Your program seems to be a endless loop that gets discovered by Red and stopped as the cursor is not advancing

Comment: changing rules dynamically is weird for a use case which is rather simple: is it really mandatory aren't there any other solutions ?

Comment: Ok, I added a pure Red solution without self modification but with conditional break

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative parametrized way to parse it:

```
div: ["<div" 4 skip some ["</div>" break | div | skip] | skip]
div-rule: [to "<div" div]

n: 1
parse src compose [(n - 1) div-rule copy text div-rule to end]
```

With `n: 1`, it will extract the first root `<div>`, with `n: 2`, the second one, and so one. It should be possible to also parametrize the nested rules to extract arbitrary `<div>` sections.